# How to parse int while updating a field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, int

I have a mysql query

```
UPDATE table SET number=number*1.06
```

How do I parse number as int in sql command so that the number that ends up in the table is an integer?

Comment: if `number` type is varchar you can use `(number * 1) *1.06`

Comment: thank you but that did not work

Comment: can you post the sample data from your table

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET number=ROUND(number*1.06)
```

did it

Answer (score 0):

> How do I parse number as int in sql command so that the number that ends up in the table is an integer?

Use `CAST` as `DECIMAL` on the output.

**Example**:

```
UPDATE table SET number = CAST( number * 1.06 as DECIMAL( 10, 0 ) );
```

**Working Example**:

```
create table var_int( vi varchar(10) );
insert into var_int values( 6 ), ( 4 ), ( 7 );
select vi
     , @vc:=( vi * 1.9 ) as vc
     , cast( @vc as decimal( 10, 0 ) ) as int_val from var_int;
```

**Result**:

```
+------+--------------------+---------+
| v    | vc                 | int_val |
+------+--------------------+---------+
| 6    | 11.399999999999999 |      11 |
| 4    |                7.6 |       8 |
| 7    | 13.299999999999999 |      13 |
+------+--------------------+---------+
```

Comment: using ROUND is probably cleaner though